# In the film “Lifeforce” (1985), how is the twist at the end possible?

Tags: lifeforce

In the movie [*Lifeforce*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifeforce_(film)) (1985), the antagonists are three "energy vampires" who drain a victim of their life force. Each victim must then also steal energy from others to survive, thus creating a self-perpetuating "plague" of vampirism.

The protagonist, astronaut Colonel Tom Carlsen, claims to feel a connection to the original three creatures and uses this ability to help track them down.

However, at the end, it is revealed that Carlsen…

> …is himself a vampire. This was apparently foreshadowed earlier when his crew found the vampires in space and he alone felt invigorated while the others felt drained.

It's said the vampires had visited Earth before, but that was centuries ago. Also, their true form is a giant Man-Bat type of creature. So this reveal never made a whole lot of sense to me.

#### How is this "twist" possible?

Comment: I remember the plot being the alien vampire woman was collecting the life-force she and the other male vampires were harvesting from each "infection", and sending it up to the starship embedded in Halley's Comet.  The vampires weren't just telepathic, but shapeshifters.  Carlsen was turned into a vampire by mating with the female vampire on board the Space Shuttle that investigated the alien star ship. This is what gave him the telepathic connection to the female vampire. Supposedly the vampire ship had been visiting Earth with Halley's Comet every 75-76 years.

Comment: @jhpace1 I'll have to go back and watch it again, I didn't think they mated until the end. And Carlsen didn't just have the bond, he also seemed to have the siphoning ability, albeit a much more subtle version. Maybe he was accidentally left behind and locked into human form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Carlsen was specifically targeted by the space vampires for seduction.

#### As for why Carlsen was considered a “special” human who was not completely drained of his life force? Who knows.

He was a vampire because “[Space Girl](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Space_Girl)” is a shapeshifter who changed her form to be more appealing to him. Thus why he felt invigorated at the beginning of the film: He was never a vampire at all at the point they boarded the alien ship but basically the space vampires read each of the crew member’s minds and shapeshifted into a form that would appeal to the astronauts.

And [as the Wikipedia page for the film states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifeforce_(film)):

> “Carlsen is flown to London, where he describes the course of events, including feeling compelled to open the female vampire's container and share his life force with her, culminating in the draining of the Churchill crew's life force. Carlsen explains that he set fire to the shuttle with the intention of saving Earth from the same fate and escaped in the pod. However, when he is hypnotised, it becomes clear that Carlsen possesses a psychic link to the female alien, and he reveals her ability to shapeshift.”

She was never a sexy nude space lady to begin with but that is the form she changed to when she read Carlsen’s mind when he and others boarded their ship.

Further backed up by this dialogue from the film as found via [IMDB quotes from the film](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089489/characters/nm0706883):

> **Col. Colin Caine**: Tell me again how the girl over powered you.
>
> **Dr. Bukovsky**: She... was the most overwhelmingly feminine presence I have ever encountered. I was drawn to her on a level...
>
> **Col. Colin Caine**: Was it sexual?
>
> **Dr. Bukovsky**: Yes. Overwhelmingly so, and horrible. Loss of control.

As well as this:

> **Col. Tom Carlsen**: It was the hardest thing I ever did.
>
> **Dr. Bukovsky**: We understand. It must have taken great courage to try and...
>
> **Col. Tom Carlsen**: No, you don't understand. Part of me didn't want to leave. She killed all my friends and I still didn't want to leave. Leaving her was the hardest thing I ever did.”

And this is further explained I this transcript of the film dialogue of Space Girl while in Dr. Armstrong’s body during the hypnosis scene:

> Our bodies are unimportant.
>
> As you and your men have approached in your ship, we changed them.
>
> For you.
>
> We entered your minds and found there new bodies.
>
> I took my shape from your mind.
>
> I took your language.
>
> I became the woman I found there, in your deepest thoughts, your deepest needs.
>
> I am the feminine in your mind, Carlsen.

Now as to why Carlsen was psychically seduced by Space Girl that way instead of simply being desiccated and drained of his life force? Who knows. The script to the film has tons of holes. But I guess Carlsen was a classic example of a victim a vampire had sympathy for?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the first paragraph but I'm having trouble. So basically, he was a vampire, but at an earlier point, he wasn't yet?

Comment: I meant the one that came after the two bold titles